# How to calculate the angle of the resultant force using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, geometry, physics

First of all i have to say im representing electric field with canvas
Well, i have three canvas, (canvas1, canvas2, canvas3).

canvas1 = arrow

canvas2 = arrow

canvas3 = resultant force arrow

Javascript:

```
        let angle1 = positivo1; //positivo1 = rotation angle of the canvas1
        let angle2 = 180 - positivo2; //positivo2 = rotation angle of the canvas2
        let angleBetween = 180 - (angle1 + angle2);

        let resultantForce = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(f1,2) + Math.pow(f2,2) - 2*f1*f2*Math.cos(angleBetween)); //F1 and F2 are the forces

        let senBeta = ((Math.sin(angleBetween)/resultantForce))*f1;
        let Beta = Math.asin(senBeta);

        let resultantAngle = angle1 + Beta;

        canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${resultantAngle}deg)`;
```

Im using this schema

[image]

Now im using this schema

[image]

Comment: If you represent forces as vectors (x,y components), then result is just sum of vectors. You'll avoid a lot of problems with vector approach.

Comment: and just use " let senBeta = ((Math.sin(angleBetween)/resultantForce))*f1;"  to get the angle?

Comment: When you have sum vector `resultx, resulty`, you can get direction angle as `Math.atan2(resulty,resultx)`

Comment: And that multiplied by 180/Math.PI to get the degrees?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: I post the new schema, if you can pls see it

Comment: OK, but why do you use force difference? Your second picture shows that you need sum F1 + F2